# Erro de sintaxe no print

Tags: python

código:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="xxx.xxx.x.xx", user="xxxxx", passwd="xxxxxxxx", db="xxxxxxx")


cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT Dias, HoraConsulta, HoraSaida, nome, Consulta, centrodb.LocalConsulta.Descricao, Contato FROM centrodb.RegistoConsultas LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.LocalConsulta ON centrodb.LocalConsulta.Id = centrodb.RegistoConsultas.`Local` LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.utentes ON centrodb.utentes.codigoutente = centrodb.RegistoConsultas.Utente LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.DiasSemana ON centrodb.DiasSemana.Id = centrodb.RegistoConsultas.DiaSemana")

myresult = cursor.fetchall()

for linha in myresult:
                dia = linha['Dias']
                hora = linha['HoraConsulta']
                saida = linha['HoraSaida']
                utente = linha['nome']
                consulta = linha['Consulta']
                local = linha['Descricao']
                contato =linha['Contato']

print​(​"Dia:", dia)
print​(​"Hora Consulta:", hora)
print​(​"Hora Saída:", saida)
print​(​"Utente:", utente)
print​(​"Consulta:", consulta)
print​(​"Local:", local)
print​(​"Contato:", contato)
```

O erro de sintaxe é na primeira linha do print.
No terminal o erro é:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

o que devi ser exibido nos prints:

- Dia: quarta-feira
- hora: 11:00:00
- saida: 10:15:00
- utente: xxxxxxxxxx
- consulta: Dentista
- local: Hospital São João
- contato: xxxxxxx

Vou mostrar só o motivo de afirmar que não é problema da query:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="xxx.xxx.x.xx", user="xxxxx", passwd="xxxxxxxx", db="xxxxxxx")


cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT Dias, HoraConsulta, HoraSaida, nome, Consulta, centrodb.LocalConsulta.Descricao, Contato FROM centrodb.RegistoConsultas LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.LocalConsulta ON centrodb.LocalConsulta.Id = centrodb.RegistoConsultas.`Local` LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.utentes ON centrodb.utentes.codigoutente = centrodb.RegistoConsultas.Utente LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.DiasSemana ON centrodb.DiasSemana.Id = centrodb.RegistoConsultas.DiaSemana")

myresult = cursor.fetchall()

print(myresult)
```

Assim imprime o resultado existente na tabela

Comment: Esses print não deveriam estar dentro do laço? E a indentação continua estranha.

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss, esse laço não é o for que faço antes do print? A indentação que se refere é no print? Estou a iniciar no python, mas é dificil pedir ajuda porque estão sempre a colocar votos negativos nas perguntas. Penso que não está a existir bom senso. A pergunta não está explicita?

Comment: Não está. Geralmente no Python se usa apenas 4 espaços de recuo, você usou 16 dentro do laço, sendo um indício que isso possa estar errado no seu código. Amém de que a indentação é essencial no Python. Atualmente os prints estão fora do laço, então este estaria iterando sobre os resultados, definido variáveis e fazendo nada com elas, o que não faz sentido. É necessário que você garanta que o código na pergunta esteja exatamente como o original e, de preferência, faça um [mcve].

Comment: Por exemplo, você cita que o erro está na linha 22, mas seu código possui apenas 16 linhas. Não temos como saber onde acusou o erro. Poste na pergunta o código completo, junto com a mensagem de erro na íntegra.

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss  já coloquei o código todo, e a informação do erro no terminal é mesmo só esse.

Comment: Não seria nessa parte? "centrodb.LocalConsulta.Id = centrodb.RegistoConsultas.`Local`"

Comment: @Victor Laio não, essa parte do código está correta

Comment: Então tem certeza que ele conseguiu conectar com sucesso no BD? Se mudar a query pra um simples select * from ele vai executar?

Comment: Se não encontrar registros no banco não entrará no laço e não definirá as variáveis. Nesse caso, o que deveria ser exibido nos prints?

Comment: Se retirar tudo desde o for até ao fim e colocar `print(myresult)` ele imprime a única linha que existe na tabela da base de dados, mas se fizer o `for`, defenir as variáveis e depois fizer `print` a cada uma das variáveis, na primeira linha do `print` da primeira variável dá erro de sintaxe, que diz sintaxe inválida

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss editei a pergunta com o que devia ser exibido nos prints

Comment: (pessoal ,quando for assim favor orientar o AP a copiar e colar a mensagem de erro completa. Ela traria a linha e coluna do erro nesse caso)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use um editor de textos adequado para programação

Ao copiar o seu código e edita-lo para o exemplo abaixo, descobri que existem caractéres invisíveis, não imprimíveis, entre o `(` e o `"`) Verificando aqui, vi que é o caracer `\u200b` com o nome "ZERO WIDTH SPACE". Ou seja, o seu editor de textos colocou um caractére louco não imprimível e invisível em posições aleatórias no seu código.

Eu estava finalizando minha resposta inicial - e nela dou dicas sobre o editor.
Mas eu achei que você tinha usado o "notepad" que já é bem ruim - processadores de texto, como o Word, OpenOffice, wordpad, são mais provavelmente o que você usou por aí  -essas ferramentas são **absolutamente impróprias**  para editar código.
Existem centenas de editores de programação, dezenas de qualidade muito boa e gratuitos, inclusive um que vem instalado com o próprio Python.

## resposta original

À parte do que foi dito nos comentários - a sintaxe desse script parece estar correta, e ele funcionaria tanto em Python 2 quanto em Python 3

MAS - se você estiver salvando o arquivo com a codificação padrão do Windows - que é Latin-1 (também conhecida como cp-1252), por conta da primeira linha do arquivo: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` que faz o Python ler o arquivo como utf-8, ele vai dar erro de sintaxe na linha `print​(​"Hora Saída:", saida)` - por conta do caractere acentuado.

A codificação de fato do arquivo é feita pelo editor que você usa pra editar o programa. Nele deve ter a opção de selecionar a codificação. Sem isso, o caratctere acentuado `í` vai ser gravado no seu arquivo .py como um byte que é inválido em utf-8.

Ajudaria se você colasse o erro inteiro, em vez de só a primeira palavra da mensagem de erro. (se for isso, ele vai dizer que é um "unicode decode error")

Você não menciona a versão do Python - espero que seja Python 3- não faz sentido trabalhar com Python 2 hoje em projetos novos. Você pode simplesmente remover a primeira linha com a indicação de codificação - mas procure salvar seu arquivo como utf-8 do mesmo jeito. Dica: o "notepad" que acompanha o Windows não é uma ferramenta na qual é possivel escrever código Python - além do problema de codificação, ele não tem a funcionalidade de identação automática.

Junto com a instalação do Python no Windows é instalado o `idle` - é um ambiente interativo e IDE simples, no entando bastante completo, que vai funcionar bem pra isso.

Além da questão de codificação e de usar Python 3: a recoemdnação pra identação no Python é de 4 espaços - a sintaxe da linguagem deixa livre *quanto* você usa de identação, desde que em cada bloco ela seja mantida - por isso não dá erro com sua identação de mais de 10 espaços - masesse tipo d identçaão não tem nenhuma vantagem nem teórica nem prática, seja pra escrever, seja pra ler, seja pra manter o código.  (mas é uma pista de que você deve ter usado um editor de textos sem identação automática - já que ele usam 4, no máximo 8, espaços por padrão, e teve que ficar colocando espaços manualmente em cada linha)

E por fim, quando passar o erro de sintaxe, você provavelmente vai querer colocar os "print" todos dentro do laço  `for` para imprimir todos os registros e não apenas o último.

Na verdade, não há a menor necessidade de se fazer aquele bloco de atribuição de variáveis - os valores são tão utilizáveis diretamente de dentro do dicionário, quanto de variáveis "próprias" pra cada um  - nesse caso, você só está digitando mais.

Mais ainda, as strisn em Python tem um método `format` para o qual você pode passar um dicionário direto - isso faz com que você possa escrever sua formatação de forma direta num único print - e passando os dados de uma vez.  Dá para usar a delimietação de strigns com três aspas  `"""` para ter mais de uma linha dentro da string a ser impressa. (note que o `.format` é da string, e não do print)

```
from textwrap import dedent

for linha in myresult:
    print​(dedent("""​
    Dia: {Dias}
    Hora Consulta: {HoraConsulta}
    Hora Saída: {HoraSaida}
    ....
    """.format(**linha)
```

## Como verificar os seus caractéres malucos em Python:

A própria linguagem Python pode ser usada para achar caractéres invisíveis e de controle como o que está no código acima. (Vai depender das capacidades de copiar e colar esses caractéres no seu sistema e no seu terminal - Windows não é a melhor ferramenta). Mas se além de ver os códigos você quiser ver o nome Unicode dos caractéres dá pra fazer assim - o texto com a linha que quero análisar eu copiei e colei diretamente do seu código acima:

```
In [100]: for char in """print("Dia:", dia)""": 
     ...:     print(char, hex(ord(char)), unicodedata.name(char)) 
     ...:                                                                                                
p 0x70 LATIN SMALL LETTER P
r 0x72 LATIN SMALL LETTER R
i 0x69 LATIN SMALL LETTER I
n 0x6e LATIN SMALL LETTER N
t 0x74 LATIN SMALL LETTER T
 0x200b ZERO WIDTH SPACE
( 0x28 LEFT PARENTHESIS
 0x200b ZERO WIDTH SPACE
" 0x22 QUOTATION MARK
D 0x44 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D
i 0x69 LATIN SMALL LETTER I
a 0x61 LATIN SMALL LETTER A
: 0x3a COLON
" 0x22 QUOTATION MARK
, 0x2c COMMA
  0x20 SPACE
d 0x64 LATIN SMALL LETTER D
i 0x69 LATIN SMALL LETTER I
a 0x61 LATIN SMALL LETTER A
) 0x29 RIGHT PARENTHESIS
```